# Abs with lower fat better results

Tags: workout, abdominals

I lose body fat cutting my meals.I see  that my abs seems more.I can't say is strong but more showable.What I came here to ask is ,if I cut food,only vegetables and fruits and salads,will my abs become more visible(effective ) with workouts?With other words I am gona reduce my body fat more,the question is reducing body fat from stomach area and working out abs will produce more showable results but and visible results?Visible results I mean stronger abs,because my abs seemed like not as strong as I wanted.The lower body fat has someone the better for abs to be visible? 
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could eat almost anything (on a caloric deficit) and drop bodyfat. If you are reaching your macronutrient and micronutrient goals, that will help even more. If your abs haven’t grown enough though, you won’t see them even at lower body fat percentages.

Find a “TDEE Calculator” (google), do 200-500 less calories than what your TDEE is, and you’ll drop bodyfat. If you want to build muscle, try getting 1.5-2 times your kg body weight in grams of protein AND keep your calorie deficit at 200 or less than your TDEE.

Comment: I ask if less body fat more can give more grow to abs.You go to further.Easy question I did :) If I understand you. You mean if I less my body fat it will help my self more for building abs ,right?

Comment: Having less body fat will make abs more visible, yes. However, the size of your abs will determine how soon you see them while shedding fat (like starting to see them at 15% bodyfat instead of 14%).

Comment: The answer is in comment.Please edit your answer ,thank you :)